# copying row from old .xls extension without changing cell formatting in python

Tags: python, excel, xls

I am trying to copy entire row of .XLS files containing specific code provided by user's input. The files have a column with date provided with custom formatting. Due to that, once the row is copied, the output converts date from the file to floating number like this : 44981.0

I was using xlrd module to read .xls files. So far I came up with function below.

```
def copy_xls_row(file_name):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name, formatting_info=True)
    file = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    global rows_list
    for row_nums in range(file.nrows):
        row_value = file.row_values(row_nums)
        if req_code in row_value:
            row_as_string = " ".join([str(value) for value in row_value])
            rows_list.append(row_as_string)

    return rows_list
```

Function itself is later being used in base with open. Do you know if there is a chance of implementing code to copy the data without changing formatting in xlrd or maybe there is any other module for this? I would like to not convert xls to xlsx.

Also, jus to mention, date formats may vary as the idea for code is to work on different layouts.